# invalid conversion from 'QWidget*' to 'QwtPlotCanvas*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I'm trying to compile a program (found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lisem/) by following the instructions said by the author. However, when compiling it in Qt Creator, it gives the error:

```
invalid conversion from 'QWidget*' to 'QwtPlotCanvas*' [-fpermissive]
```

for this line in [LisUImapplot.cpp](http://sourceforge.net/p/lisem/code/HEAD/tree/lisem/ui_full/LisUImapplot.cpp)

```
186 picker = new MyPicker( MPlot->canvas() );
```

link to its header file (LisUImapplot.h) can be found on the same folder as the cpp file.

```
class MyPicker: public QwtPlotPicker
{
public:
    MyPicker( QwtPlotCanvas *canvas ):
        QwtPlotPicker( canvas )
    {
        setTrackerMode( AlwaysOn );
    }

    virtual QwtText trackerTextF( const QPointF &pos ) const
    {
        QColor bg( Qt::white );
        bg.setAlpha( 100 );

        QwtPlotItemList list = plot()->itemList(QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotSpectrogram);
        QwtPlotSpectrogram * sp = static_cast<QwtPlotSpectrogram *> (list.at(1));
        double z = sp->data()->value(pos.x(), pos.y());
        QString txt = "";
        if (z > -1e10)
            txt.sprintf( "%.3f", z );
        QwtText text = QwtText(txt);
        text.setColor(Qt::black);
        text.setBackgroundBrush( QBrush( bg ) );
        return text;
    }
};
```

I hope you can help me on this. Thank you!

I am using Qt 5.1.1 MinGW 32-bit and Qwt 6.1.0

Comment: What is return type of `MPlot->canvas()`? What type has `picker` pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QwtPlot::canvas()](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot.html#a53f836bb4ec09c766e3d871ea4be28f7) returns a `QWidget`. Your `MyPicker` constructor is expecting a `QwtPlotCanvas` type parameter.

You can cast it to a `QwtPlotCanvas`:

```
QwtPlotCanvas *canvas = qobject_cast<QwtPlotCanvas*>(MPlot->canvas());
if(canvas)
{
   picker = new MyPicker(canvas);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do constructor?

```
MyPicker( QwtPlotCanvas *canvas ):
    QwtPlotPicker( canvas ){}
```

In the old version of Qwt was QwtPlotPicker::QwtPlotPicker(QwtPlotCanvas *canvas);
In the Qwt 6.1.* is QwtPlotPicker::QwtPlotPicker(QWidget *parent);

You have to do

```
MyPicker( QWidget *canvas ):
    QwtPlotPicker( canvas ){}
```